# Ruby On Rails: access a variable from a form, without saving it to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have 3 pages:

[Page 1] Index

[Page 2] User enter value in a form.

[Page 3] Do calculation on the value entered and output it on this page.

I as wondering how do i do this? I do not want to save the data in any database.

Thank you =)

***Added info 20100628 based on feedback. Thank you! ***

for PHP, I could user $_GET and %_POST function. I am not sure how to do it on ROR.
[Page 1: index.html]

Amount in bank: 
Interest rate (%):

[Page 2: interest_cal.php]
In 10 yrs, the total amount in your bank would be _______

Answer (score 2, accepted):

welcome to stackoverflow. This is a programming QA Website, so it would be nice to see some Code, to see more clearly what You want. But I think what you want is a tableless model. There are two good screencasts by [railscasts](http://railscasts.com):

1. [Tableless Model](http://railscasts.com/episodes/193-tableless-model) (Rails 2)
2. [Active Model](http://railscasts.com/episodes/219-active-model) (Rails 3)

Answer (score 0):

Just declare attribute in your model and use it.

```
attr_accessor :value
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use `params[:field_name]` in Rails, this is similar to `$_REQUEST['field_name']` in PHP (except `params` in Rails doesn't include cookies, as $_REQUEST does)

Answer (score 0):

> I do not want to save the data in any
>   database.

its simple
don't create any model.
or if you must create model. create model without inheritance from  ActiveRecord::Base

```
class UserModel
```

but not

```
class UserModel <  ActiveRecord::Base
```

> for PHP, I could user $_GET and %_POST
>   function.

use **params** variable in controller

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

Page1 -> index

Page2 ->

say you have a model called user which is not inherited from ActiveRecord, so it will be looks like this

```
class User
  attr_accessor :my_value   
end
```

and you will have a form like this

```
<% form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.text_field :my_value %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit 'send value' %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

** sorry i had to remove some tags

and in your form post action (in controller), you can get the value as

```
params[:user][:my_value]
```

hope this helps

cheers

sameera

Comment: you should format your code properly the next time. It can be done by indenting each code line by 4 spaces or mark the code and hit the code button of the editor (the one with the ones and zeroes on it)

Comment: Thank you sameera207 and Jens F.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a model, but just simply a variable, I would prefer using form_tag instead of form_for

```
<%= form_tag :action => "your_page_3_action" $>
    <%= text_field_tag :some_var %>
```

Something like that. And then you could get back the :some_var through:

```
def your_page_3_action
  params[:some_var] # that's your input valut
```